# C# TCP Socket Communicator - handle special messages between client and server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, windows-phone-8, tcp

I want to learn about socket communication so I decided to try to write WP 8.1 text communicator. It is based on TCP sockets. I almost managed to finish it, but I am searching for improvemenets.

What is worth mentioning I use a socket server between phones (console application), to avoid problems with private ip addresses. It contains information about all connected users and forwards messages to clients (for instance user A sends message to user B, so firstly message goes to server and server forward it to destination address).

The problem appeared when i realized that I need to send special messages from server to client and vice versa (for example when two clients want to have conversation, they send request to server, so it knows where to forward messages).

This is my connection listener method from server application

```
private void ConnectionListener()
    {
        IPEndPoint localDataEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(LocalIpAddress), 1234);
        IPEndPoint localMessageEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(LocalIpAddress), 4321);
        Socket dataConnectionListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Socket messageConnectionListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            dataConnectionListener.Bind(localDataEndPoint);
            dataConnectionListener.Listen(100);
            messageConnectionListener.Bind(localMessageEndPoint);
            messageConnectionListener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                TcpSocket.clientDone.Reset();
                IAsyncResult tmp1 = dataConnectionListener.BeginAccept(ConnectionCallback, null);
                IAsyncResult tmp2 = messageConnectionListener.BeginAccept(ConnectionCallback, null);
                TcpSocket.clientDone.WaitOne();
                Socket dataSocket = dataConnectionListener.EndAccept(tmp1);
                Socket messageSocket = messageConnectionListener.EndAccept(tmp2);

                TcpSocket tmpTcpSocket = new TcpSocket(dataSocket, messageSocket);
                tmpTcpSocket.Start();
                connectedUsersSockets.Add(tmpTcpSocket);
                UpdateConnectedUserList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.E("Connection listener ran into an exception", ex);
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have created two TCP sockets to liesten on different ports. `dataSocket` is for normal messages and `messageSocket` is for special messages (sorry for confusing names, I have to refractor code).

On client side it works the same way: there are two different socket to communicate with and through the server.

I wanted to avoid managing two sockets rather then one. But the only way I can imagine is that on every received message server would have to check if it's special (and handle it in special way) or just send to client.

**The question:** Is there a better way to manage these special messages?

Thanks to all in advance!

P.S.
Sorry for my poor english, it's not my native language

Comment: Your question is "primarily opinion based", not a good fit for StackOverflow. My opinion: either approach will work. As you've already noted, either approach involves some pro and some con: two sockets simplify the coding a bit, but of course consume a twice as many OS socket resources (but probably not the resources that would be a limiting factor). On the other hand, a single socket is more efficient but requires somewhat more complicated code. Personally, I'd go with a single socket, but I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with making your life easier and using two. :)

Comment: The question was meant to be more about efficiency/elegance then opinion. I know that both ways works fine, because I test them (unfortunately with only 3 devices connnected). I wanted to know which approach is faster and more elegant.

Comment: "Elegant" is _absolutely_ opinion-based. It's one of the most clearly subjective aspects of programming you can find. As far as efficiency goes, there are different kinds of efficiency and the question of performance (one kind of efficiency) is often of lower priority than efficiency related to developer productivity and/or code quality. Again, prioritizing these different kinds of efficiencies is very much opinion-based, or at least tied closely to a specific scenario in a way that prevents anyone but you from answering.

Comment: As I said, one socket is _clearly_ more efficient than two by at least one particular measure. But using two sockets has advantages in terms of developer efficiency and code correctness/reliability that are harder to quantify. There's not much you can expect outsiders like those of us reading your question to be able to offer in terms of precise, _objective_, actionable information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I understand that neither of these approaches is better/worse. I have to experiment with them a bit more to find better solution for my messenger.